# String split question using "*"

Tags: java, regex, string

Let's say have a string...

```
String myString =  "my*big*string*needs*parsing";
```

All I want is to get an split the string into "my" , "big" , "string", etc.
So I try

```
myString.split("*");
```

returns 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0

`*` is a special character in regex so I try escaping....

```
myString.split("\\*");
```

same exception.  I figured someone would know a quick solution.  Thanks.

Comment: your right \\* does work, I was using it from an array...
myArray[x].split("\\*"); and it was throwing an exception but if I if turn myArray[x] into a string first and then run it it works... thanks for the answers :)

Comment: i mean double \ in the above comment....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`split("\\*")` works with me.

Answer (score 5):

One escape `\` will not do the trick in Java 6 on Mac OSX, as `\` is reserved for `\b \t \n \f \r \'\"` and `\\`. What you have seems to work for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString =  "my*big*string*needs*parsing";
    String[] a = myString.split("\\*");
    for (String b : a) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

outputs:

> my
>  big 
> string
>  needs
>  parsing

Answer (score 1):

http://arunma.com/2007/08/23/javautilregexpatternsyntaxexception-dangling-meta-character-near-index-0/

Should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`myString.split("\\*");` is working fine on Java 5. Which JRE do you use.

Comment: Single slash won't work; \* isn't a special character. I think you made a typo:)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("my*big*string*needs*parsing", "\*");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the split method takes a regular expression, not a plain string.

The '*' character means match the previous character zero or more times, thus it is not valid to specify it on its own.

So it should be escaped, like following

`split("\\*")`