# SMS Payment system

Tags: java, smslib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String split question using “*”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308137/string-split-question-using)

I'm working on sms payment system using Java particularly netbeans. The application can send and receive messages using smsLib. My question is I want clients for example to text a message like pay#merchant#amount, how can I split the message when receiving it in my code?

help will be thankful